# C# Connection String Without Windows Authentication Mode

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I tried a lot but couldn't solve this problem. I want just my connection sql in c# by sql server authentication mode. I don't want windows authentication. When I enable windows authentication mode then my application does not work. What can I do?

This my connection string:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myservername;Initial Catalog=mydatabesename;User Id=myuserId; Password=mypassword;Integrated Security=True");
```

If I change my password in code it works. Also when I delete `Integrated security=true` then shows me the following error:

> Login failed for user

Comment: You need to enable SQL Server Authentication in SQL Server itself. It is disabled by default.

Comment: Do you see the login attempt on your server? are you sure the user created has permissions to the database etc that you wish and the password you're giving it

Comment: ı enabled sql server authentication in sql server it self ı connection in sql management studio it is not problem my problem is in c# code ı want dont use windows authentication ı just use sql authentication mode

Comment: if you don't want windows authentication, `Integrated Security` must be false

Comment: ı tired but it does not work it show me login failed for user

Comment: are user name and password correct?

Comment: yes of cource because ı connect this username and password on sql server itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys ı solved when ı add new login also tick the sysadmin new login in sql server and use it  on conenction string in c#  ı think this error by the user ıd 'sa' ı change new user name and password then it works thnks all people who try help me

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the mixed mode authentication?

Did you grant to the user the access to the DB?

you can do it using [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/mt238290.aspx)

Did you restart SQL services after changing the mixed mode authentication?

Some of the server level properties takes only after a SQL restart , one such is authentication modes.

> Start - > View Local Services -> SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) > restart it

Comment: yes ı enabled miixed authentication and restart sql services but it does not work when ı change integrated security =true it works but change false it error login for user 'sa'

Comment: Did you grant to the user  the access to the DB?

Comment: OK guys ı solved when ı add new login also tick the sysadmin new login in sql server and use it  on conenction string in c#  ı think this error by the user ıd 'sa' ı change new user name and password then it works thnks all people who try help me

Answer (score 0):

You just need to edit your connection string to include the user name and password as below:

Scaffold-DbContext

```
"Server=DatabaseServer;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=false; User Id=ServeruserName; Password=ServerPassword;"
```

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models/DB
```